# Java FX database problem when adding new datas

Tags: database, javafx, event-handling, tableview, derby

I have a database problem. I want to create a simple Java FXML application which could help to my friend to search the protein/potassium content of the foods, because of kidney disease.

I have 4 class variables: name, protein, potassium, and id for the database (to identify the variables in the database).

I use Java DB - derby.

My application has 2 pane: 1. „home screen” has a textfield, where you have to type the name of the food you looking for, and if you click to the „search” button it will search the appropriate data from the database and show it in a table on the next pane. (the searching isn't working yet – you can type anything in the textfield what you want and then click to "Search", but no results showed yet in the table).

On the next page you can see the table, and at the bottom, you can add new data. I did a test to make sure the database works correctly, so the second pane I wrote a test Name, test Protein content, test Potassium content, and then click to the „add” button. Then the table shows just the potassium value, and puts this value in the first column instead of the „potassium column”. By the way, the db works but just stores the last value in the first column. I think I have a mistake somewhere in the setTableData method, but I run out of the ideas.

Here is my link to my files: https://github.com/Capkit/FirstProjects

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me!

Comment: Your copy and paste forgot to change the column names when you set your cell factories.

Comment: omg. Thank you!  Seriously, I've checked the code so many times and I did not see this. I am happy about no bigger problem was the mistake!